# What is the best way to create custom filters for a repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I have a controller called `CircuitController` where I want to retrieve an Entity both from the ID and from a reference:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/circuits/{id}")
    public EntityModel<Circuit> getCircuitById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Circuit circuit = circuitRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CircuitNotFoundException(id));

        return circuitModelAssembler.toModel(circuit);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/circuits/")
    public EntityModel<Circuit> getCircuitByRef(@RequestParam(value="ref") String ref) {
        // no "circuitRepository.findByRef(ref) method here.
    }
```

For the second method, there is no `findByRef(String ref)` method already implemented in the `JPARepository`

I came up with 2 solutions:

1. In my `CircuitRepository` class I can define a default method `findByRef(String ref)` to do exactly what I need and then use it from the `CircuitController` class.

```
@Repository
public interface CircuitRepository extends JpaRepository<Circuit, Long>  {

    default Circuit findCircuitByRef(String ref) {
        Optional<Circuit> circuit = this.findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(circuit1 -> circuit1.getCircuitRef().equals(ref))
                .findAny();

        if (circuit.isPresent()) {
            return circuit.get();
        } else {
            throw new CircuitNotFoundException(ref);
        }
    }
}
```

and then I can do:

```
   @GetMapping("/api/circuits/")
    public EntityModel<Circuit> getCircuitByRef(@RequestParam(value="ref") String ref) {
        Circuit circuit = circuitRepository.findCircuitByRef(ref);
        return circuitModelAssembler.toModel(circuit);
    }
```

2. The 2nd option would be to implement the logic in my `getCircuitByRef` method directly like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/api/circuits/")
    public EntityModel<Circuit> getCircuitByRef(@RequestParam(value="ref") String ref) {
        Circuit circuit;
        Optional<Circuit> optionalCircuit = circuitRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(circuit1 -> circuit1.getCircuitRef().equals(ref))
                .findAny();

        if (optionalCircuit.isPresent()) {
            circuit = optionalCircuit.get();
        } else {
            throw new CircuitNotFoundException(ref);
        }
        return circuitModelAssembler.toModel(circuit);
    }
```

I'm not sure what is the best practice here, or how the code standards for spring applications are. On thing I've noticed is that with the first option, I can then later mock my `CircuitRepository` interface and mock the `findByRef` method for UT purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is a better practice to separate functional components in a project. I prefer to do it like this - Controller is responsible for handling the API calls, Repository - data access. So, I would stick with the 1st option.

As for the actual implementation, I would recommend using Spring's functionality. There is no method `findCircuitByRef(String ref)`, but Spring can create an implementation of this method for you. What you can do is the following:

```
@Repository
public interface CircuitRepository extends JpaRepository<Circuit, Long>  {
    Circuit findByCircuitRef(String ref);
}
```

What Spring will do behind the scenes is the following - it will create an implementation of this method, which does what you are doing in the default implementation.
You can see more information on the topic [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Comment: Oh I didn't know Spring can implement this by itself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot to say that the exact method naming is important. If your `Circuit` class has a property `circuitRef`, then the method that Spring will recognise is `findByCircuitRef`, it will not recognise `findCircuitByRef`.